# How to return results from column A only when all aritmetic results in column B for A are the same

Tags: sql-server

I'm stumped and wanted to ask for some pointers.

I have a table which record orders in multiple columns;

```
COL_A - Order ID
COL_B - Order line
COL_C - Log of activities done on order line, 2=order accepted, 950=item in stock
COL_D - Stock Check, uses arithmetic function to work out if item is in stock, takes COL_C and divides by 950 to zero decimal places. 0 = no, 1 = yes
COL_E - Order status
COL_F - Product code
```

Orders are saved then the log is updated when actions are carried out, accumulating the value with action value, so an action log value of 952 means the order has been accepted & item is in stock.
Col_D uses the COL_C log value to indicate if the ordered item is in stock. This just divides the log value by 950 to indicate if in stock.

I need the query to return orders and all order lines only when ALL the ordered items for an order are in stock.

Example
Data table:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Comment: SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE Col_D = 1

Comment: That will return all rows which are in stock (=1) regardless of order ID. I need it to return all lines per order ID where every order line for that order ID is in stock for that order ID. I am not interested in any order ID which has order rows not in stock.

Comment: Rephrase your question then.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  COL_A as "ORDER ID", 
  COL_B as "Line NO", 
  COL_C as "Action LOG", 
  COL_D as "IN stock", 
  COL_E as "Status", 
  COL_F as "Product"
where 
  COL_D = 1;
```

Comment: That will return all rows which are in stock (=1) regardless of order ID. I need it to return all lines per order ID where every order line for that order ID is in stock for that order ID. I am not interested in any order ID which has order rows not in stock.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  COL_A as "ORDER ID", 
  COL_B as "Line NO", 
  COL_C as "Action LOG", 
  COL_D as "IN stock", 
  COL_E as "Status", 
  COL_F as "Product"
FROM Table
WHERE COL_A IN
(SELECT COL_A FROM Table 
  GROUP BY COL_A
  HAVING MIN(COL_D) <> 0)
```